# C++ returns 0xC0000005 status

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. In the code below, I am probably doing something wrong, because in the terminal I get `Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 1.533 s` 
**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
    Baz* quuz;
    quuz->quux();

    return 0;
}
```

**foo.h**

```
#include <vector>

class Bar {
public:
    bool boolean_val;

};

class Baz {
private:
    std::vector<Bar> qux;
public:
    void quux();
};
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

void Baz::quux()
{
    qux[0].boolean_val = true;
}
```

Could you please highlight what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It appears that the thing you are doing wrong is not enabling compiler warnings, then fixing the warning.  The compiler should tell you that you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer `quuz`, and after that anything can happen.  The program could crash.  Or could appear to work.  Or the sky could fall, and nasal demons fly out of your nose.  Possibly even destroy the Earth (in case of such a calamity, please contact your compiler vendor as they'd prefer to fix that kind of issue than suffer the bad PR).

Comment: You are getting a segfault. `qux` is empty so `qux[0]` is accessing memory which is out of bounds which is Undefined Behaviour. Also see above comment for the actual root cause. Totally missed that but it leads to the same issue, with slightly different flavours

Comment: What is the specific topic of your C++ textbook where this practice problem is from? There must be a specific topic being covered here, and there's some part of it that you're missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Baz* quuz;
    quuz->quux();
```

Calling a function on an uninizialized pointer is no bueno.

```
void Baz::quux()
{
    qux[0].boolean_val = true;
}
```

Follows uninitiliazed `this` pointer to access `qux`. Undefined behavior invoked. You're lucky to get a crash. 0xC0000005 is accessed memory that is not mapped.